# SSRS recursive count - how to get aggregates only for the children, not the parent?

Tags: reporting-services, hierarchical-data

**Disclaimer**: I'm an SSRS n00b, so not too many rotten tomatoes please :)

I have a hierarchy of employees and managers which I had Reporting Services build using the [Recursive Parent property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283103.aspx). Here's a crude representation:

```
-Jim Bob
   Ray
  -Steve
     Ricky Bobby
     Terry
```

For example, I need a count of the people under Steve, but when I call `Count(Fields!EmployeeID.Value, "Details", Recursive)` I get **3** instead of **2**. Of course, I can just subtract 1 in the case of a count, but this won't work when I need a sum. So the real question is **how do I get a recursive aggregate that excludes the parent?**

Additional info: I only have one group which is the default Details group. It's set up just like [this example](http://blog.infotoad.com/post/2009/08/10/Working-with-a-Recursive-Hierarchy-Group-in-SQL-Reporting-Services-2008.aspx), so I'm grouping by EmployeeID and I have the recursive parent set to ManagerID.

---

**Update**

A few workarounds I've tried to no avail:

- Adding a row inside the group - yields the same results because it's still in the same scope as the other detail row.
- Adding a subtotal - doesn't work because it's outside the details group so it only renders once instead of once per manager.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider a couple of things.

1) you could provide counts in the SQL query that supplies the report, and then simply report it for each group using

```
      =FIRST(Fields!FieldThatHasCount.Value).
```

2) You may be able to use your report's code block to iteratively call a function, upping the count on a shared variable or doing some sort of arithmatic between parent sections and child sections to reflect the count when your report is presented.  I know I have run into complications with this approach depending on SSRS version and to the level of complexity, nesting, subreports etc., in your report.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I may take your first suggestion. The second idea makes me nervous because I thought I read that global variables are shared between all instances of the report, i.e. if multiple users are running it at the same time they can affect each other's results.

Comment: I did end up falling back to using SQL. I used a few UDFs because I needed to be able to reuse parts of it and summarize it in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get a recursive aggregate Sum that excludes the parent?

This should work since you still have access to the current field's value.

```
=Sum(Fields!EmployeeSalary.Value, "Details", Recursive) - Fields!EmployeeSalary.Value
```